# How can I generate a list and flatten it the same time in python?

Tags: python

This is more of a refactoring question, as the code works as is. But since I am still learning `Python`, I thought there would be a better way to do this, and I spent a few hours now digging into the other possibilities, but can't get anywhere.

So I have the following statement:

`numbers = [re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip()) for ticket in tickets]`

which obviously generates a list of lists. However, I want to have just a single list of the numbers taken out from that regex.

So this is the second line of code that flattens the above list (I found this solution here, on `StackOverflow` btw):

`flat = [item for setlist in numbers for item in setlist]`

Main thing I am trying to achieve is to have this on 1 single line. Otherwise, I could of course have a normal `for .. in` loop, that would append each number to numbers list, but I like keeping it on 1 line.

If this is the best it can get, I would also love to know that please.. :)

Comment: _This is more of a refactoring question, as the code works_ - This type of question would probably work much better on code view: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. They accept people's, working code, and could help you improve it. I suggest moving it there.

Comment: Why are you doing this with regex?

Comment: Because the numbers are in this format: 1 - 2 - 3 - 4

Comment: I have added the answer and it will work if your mentioned logic is working (though, don't know why it is down-voted). It would be great if you could also mention you content of tickets so that I could verify it

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Most of you all's answers seems fine to me. I don't don't know who would just go around down voting fine answers. Maybe this question is off-topic?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry: this question is a bad fit for Code Review.

Comment: @vaultah Why is that?  He said that - _This is more of a refactoring question, as the code works_. The part I'm going off of is him saying the code works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `chain` and `map` in single line as:

```
list(chain(*map(lambda x: re.split(' ?- ?', x.text.strip()), tickets)))
```

**Suggestion:**

There is no need to use `regex` here, because you may achieve the same using `split` function of Python. Hence, your answer will become:

```
list(chain(*map(lambda x: x.text.replace(' ', '').split('-')), tickets)))
```

**Explaination:**

`chain` function from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) library is used to umwrap the list. Below is the sample example

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> my_nested_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> list(chain(*my_nested_list))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Whereas `map` function is used to call the passed `function` (in this case `lambda` function) on each item of `list`.

```
>>> my_nested_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> map(lambda x: x[0], my_nested_list)
[1, 4]
```

And, `split` is used to split the content of string based on substring. For example:

```
>>> x = 'hey you - i am here'
>>> x.split('-')
['hey you ', ' i am here']  # Same answer as your regex
```

Comment: Updated the answer. See `suggestion` section. I do not think you need `regex` as regex are heavier compared to simple `split`

Comment: The reason why I used regex was to get rid of those spaces as well. In your example too, 'hey you ' and ' i am here', both have spaces. I'd have to trim them I guess, so 2 functions in total - split + trim.

Comment: But we are anyhow using `strip` to trim the white spaces. So, it won't matter. Also, I will like to mention, you can also `split` as `.split('- ')` i.e a `space` after `-` :)

Comment: that would work on most of the numbers. But not on the first one:

`1 - 2 - 3` in here, 1 would have a space after it. So basically if I do `split('-')`, then I would need to `strip` each element..

Comment: Ok this is what I did:
`list(chain(*map(lambda: x: x.text.strip().replace(' ', '').split('-'), tickets)))` and it works.

Comment: Then `.strip()` is not required. You may remove that from code i.e `x.text.replace(' ', '').split('-')` will work the same

Comment: I tried that, but x.text returns html textContent. Therefore, it has tons of empty spaces like tabs and carriage returns. I would need to replace them as well.

Comment: Ok. I was not knowing that you have html content. Then it required

Comment: I implemented this approach and I will accept this one. Thanks to others for their inputs, managed to learn a thing or two.

Answer (score 1):

A better idea is to add another loop over `re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip())` in the list comprehension:

```
flat = [x for ticket in tickets for x in re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip())]
```

It's also more efficient and cleaner.

By the way, you should use string methods instead of regex:

```
flat = [x.strip() for ticket in tickets for x in ticket.split('-')]
```

If you need to convert `x` to `int`, you may drop `strip()`, since `int` ignores leading and trailing whitespace.

```
flat = [int(x) for ticket in tickets for x in ticket.split('-')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's work through this one step at a time.
As a set of partially-nested for-loops, your code would be:

```
numbers = []
for ticket in tickets:
    numbers.append(re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip())
flat = []
for setlist in numbers:
    for item in setlist:
        flat.append(item)
```

Talking through it:
You have a list of tickets. Each ticket becomes one setlist when you apply the regex split to it. You then want to grab all the items in the setlist and put them in a single list. You don't actually need to have a list of all the setlists (what you called `numbers`) at any point - that's just an intermediate stage.

Refactoring this to be completely nested:

```
flat = []
for ticket in tickets:
    for item in re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip()):
         flat.append(item)
```

Now that we have a set of completely-nested for loops, it's trivial to refactor into a list or generator comprehension:

```
flat = [item for ticket in tickets for item in re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip())]
```

It's a fairly long single line, but it is a single line.

Incidentally, a regex might not be the best way to parse out numbers like that - especially if you want the actual numbers rather than strings. `re.split()` is slower than `str.split()`, and this split is simple enough that it can be done by the latter. If the numbers are integers, try:

```
flat = [int(item) for ticket in tickets for item in ticket.split('-'))]
```

And if they're floats, try:

```
flat = [float(item) for ticket in tickets for item in ticket.split('-'))]
```

This works because the `int(str)` and `float(str)` builtins automatically ignore whitespace at the start and end of a given string, so you don't need a regex to conditionally match that whitespace. The resulting numbers can still be inserted into strings if you need to do that, and should also take up somewhat less space in memory. If the numbers are integers, you lose nothing. If they're floats, you lose very little - you lose the original precision of the number, and you might run into the limits on float size if you're working with really big or really tiny stuff (but that's unlikely - see `sys.float_info` for what those limits are).

Answer (score -1):

```
sum([re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip()) for ticket in tickets], [])
```

Comment: This is *very* inefficient.

Comment: @vaultah I know, and? Read again what OP is asking... `Main thing I am trying to achieve is to have this on 1 single line`

Comment: Yep, and it's a poor solution nevertheless.

Comment: @vaultah Well, that's comment is too broad. When N is small this solution will be more than good enough. Be aware you don't need always provide the most efficient solution

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: @abarisone No thanks, with the downvote & "useful" comments I don't have more motivation to spare more seconds with this ;)

Answer (score -2):

Just substitute the first expression for `numbers` in the second expression:

```
flat = [item for setlist in [re.split(' ?- ?', ticket.text.strip()) for ticket in tickets] for item in setlist]
```

Comment: Ah I see! I was doing it without the inner square brackets. of course, this makes sense! Thank you!